# in search of convergent daughter sequences

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}\subset L^1(\Omega,\mu)$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $\Vert f_n\Vert_1\leq M$ and $\Vert Df_n\Vert_{1/2}\leq C$ uniformly in $n$.

> **Question.** Is there a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ such that $f_{n_k}\rightarrow f$ in the $L^1$-norm, for some $f\in L^1$?

Comment: What does 1/2 norm mean ?

Comment: No. If $f_n$ is $\delta$-like (in $d=1$), of height $n$ and width $1/n$, say, then you can keep $\|f'_n\|_{1/2}$ bounded.